# Assigning available inventory to event counts

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Sorry for the vague title, having difficulty wording this...

I have the following data comprising a list of forecasted number of retirements grouped by asset type and year, and another data frame with serial numbers. I'd like to assign serial numbers to each forecasted retirement.

```
retirements <- data.frame(Asset.Type = c(rep("abc", 5), rep("def", 5)), 
                          Year = c(seq(2023, 2027), seq(2023, 2027)), 
                          Num.Retired = c(0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 7, 0, 1,0))

sn <- data.frame(Asset.Type = c(rep("abc", 12), rep("def", 5)),
                 SerialNo = c(seq(from = 58043, by = 1, length.out = 12), seq(4342, by = 1, length.out = 5)))
```

The dataframes:

1. `retirements`

```
   Asset.Type Year Num.Retired
1         abc 2023           0
2         abc 2024           2
3         abc 2025           4
4         abc 2026           3
5         abc 2027           1
6         def 2023           0
7         def 2024           7
8         def 2025           0
9         def 2026           1
10        def 2027           0
```

2. `sn`

```
   Asset.Type SerialNo
1         abc    58043
2         abc    58044
3         abc    58045
4         abc    58046
5         abc    58047
6         abc    58048
7         abc    58049
8         abc    58050
9         abc    58051
10        abc    58052
11        abc    58053
12        abc    58054
13        def     4342
14        def     4343
15        def     4344
16        def     4345
17        def     4346
```

I want to do is assign a `Num.Retired`-number of serial numbers (in order from smallest to largest) to each row in `retirements`.

Edit: If there are not enough serial numbers available to meet `Num.Retired`, add in "dummy" serial numbers (in the below example "XXXX").

For example:

`output`

```
   Asset.Type Year SerialNo.Retired
1         abc 2023               NA
2         abc 2024            58043
3         abc 2024            58044
4         abc 2025            58045
5         abc 2025            58046
6         abc 2025            58047
7         abc 2025            58048
8         abc 2026            58049
9         abc 2026            58050
10        abc 2026            58051
11        abc 2027            58052
12        def 2023               NA
13        def 2024             4342
13        def 2024             XXXX
13        def 2024             XXXX
13        def 2024             XXXX
13        def 2024             XXXX
13        def 2024             XXXX
13        def 2024             XXXX
14        def 2025               NA
15        def 2026             4343
16        def 2027               NA
```

I've tried joining a list of serial numbers to each line in `retirements` and then assign in a wide format from there, but haven't had any luck getting this to work.

Looking for some approaches to attempt here.

Comment: Do you always have `Num.Retired <= SerialNo.Retired` per asset type?

Comment: Yes. `Num.Retired <= SerialNo.Retired` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uncount` to expand rows to match the count in `Num.Retired`, then `slice` the corresponding number of serial numbers and bind together.

```
library(tidyverse)

retirements |> 
  group_by(Asset.Type) |> 
  uncount(Num.Retired) |> 
  group_map(\(data, key) bind_cols(
      data, 
      sn |> filter(Asset.Type == pull(key)) |> slice(1:nrow(data)))
  ) |> 
  list_rbind() |> 
  right_join(retirements |> select(-Num.Retired), by = c("Year", "Asset.Type")) |> 
  arrange(Asset.Type, Year)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 3
    Year Asset.Type SerialNo
   <int> <chr>         <dbl>
 1  2023 abc              NA
 2  2024 abc           58043
 3  2024 abc           58044
 4  2025 abc           58045
 5  2025 abc           58046
 6  2025 abc           58047
 7  2025 abc           58048
 8  2026 abc           58049
 9  2026 abc           58050
10  2026 abc           58051
11  2027 abc           58052
12  2023 def              NA
13  2024 def            4342
14  2025 def              NA
15  2026 def            4343
16  2027 def              NA
```

Comment: This works great on the sample data above, but I'm getting the following error when I use it w/ my real data.

Error in `bind_cols()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 494) to match `..2` (size 91).

Comment: I'm thinking that the Asset.Type groups in `retirements` are not the same length as they are in `sn` (smaller number in sn).

Comment: If your actual data has characteristics that aren't represented in the example data, it's hard to help you solve for - if you can, figure out what's different and update your example.

Comment: Turns out my original data had a couple of instances where the `Num.Retired` are greater than the number of the corresponding `Asset.Type`, so the code doesn't have anymore Serial Numbers to assign. In this case, I'd like to add in a dummy `SerialNo` (e.g. "XXX") that can fill in retirements where there are no Serial numbers left. I've updated the code above to cause this same error.